# How to use html entity in my case?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a double macron characters in my app. I know I can use

`&#862;` entity for it. so `t&#862;t` will be t͞t. However, I found it very unreliable and sometimes the top line doesn't line up with two characters. Is there anyway to fix this issue? Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you Google this? Did you see this link: http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U035E/Combining_Double_Macron.

Comment: Can I use unicode in html?

Comment: Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkqeybke/)...can you tell us where/when it doesn't look right (browser/version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. You can use uni code with the pseudo selector `:before`. The `:before` pseudo selector has all major browser support (for IE > 9 doesn't work though). If you wanted to use any other uni code characters all you have to do is replace the  `&#` with `\`.

```css
span:before {
  content: "\035E";
}
```

```html
<span>tt</span>
```